# I can't understand the use of std::istream_iterator

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, istream-iterator

I can't understand the code below.

(from https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html)

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;

    std::for_each(
        in(std::cin), in(), std::cout << (_1 * 3) << " " );
}
```

The web page doesn't explain anything for the code.

What I can't understand is the line with `std::for_each` function.

`std::for_each` is defined as below.

```
template <class InputIterator, class Function>
Function for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function fn);
```

So `first` is `in(std::cin)`, `last` is just `in()`, the `function` is the `cout` statement.

Could anyone explain to me the syntax of `first` and `last` syntax and meaning in the example code?

The `first` iterator seems to be constructed with initial value `std::cin`, but what's the use of `in()` for the last value?

I also can't understand the `_1` part.

The program outputs `3 *` any number of integer values I type in.

Comment: read about the `istream_iterator` constructor. There is also a similar example: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/istream_iterator

Comment: in()  Constructs the end-of-stream iterator

Comment: also
boost::lambda::_1 is a placeholder that creates a lambda function that expects one parameter.

Comment: ah thanks (I was reading the cppreferece page and found that). @bakaDev can you post it as an answer so that I can choose it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > *Could anyone explain to me the syntax of `first` and `last` syntax and meaning in the example code?*
>
> > *The `first` iterator seems to be constructed with initial value `std::cin`, but what's the use of `in()` for the last value?*

If you look at the description of the constructor of `std::istream_iterator` you can see that `in()` constructs the end-of-stream iterator.

> ```
> istream_iterator(); //  < C++11
> constexpr istream_iterator(); // > C++11
> ```
>
> *Constructs the end-of-stream iterator, value-initializes the stored value. This constructor is `constexpr` if the initializer in the definition `auto x = T();` is a constant initializer (since C++11).*

As for `in(std::cin)`:

> ```
> istream_iterator( istream_type& stream );
> istream_iterator( const istream_iterator& other );  //< C++11
> istream_iterator( const istream_iterator& other ) = default; // > C++11
> ```
>
> *Initializes the iterator, stores the address of stream in a data member, and performs the first read from the input stream to initialize the cached value data member.*

[source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/istream_iterator)

> > *And I also can't understand the `_1` part*.

What this does is to replace the *placeholder* `_1` with every element in the iteration sequence and multiply it by 3, using the result in the output stream, as it should, given the unary function argument.

> ```
> for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), std::cout << _1 << ' ');
> ```
>
> *The expression `std::cout << _1 << ' '` defines a unary function object. The variable `_1` is the parameter of this function, a placeholder for the actual argument. Within each iteration of `for_each`, the function is called with an element of `a` as the actual argument. This actual argument is substituted for the placeholder, and the “body” of the function is evaluated.*

[source](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/lambda.html)

Comment: @ChanKim, your're welcome, yes you're right it's `boost::lambda::placeholder1_type &boost::lambda::<unnamed>::_1
`, but it's basically the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

First a little explanation about the [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) function.

The function loops over a set of iterators, from the beginning to the end, calling a function for each element in the range.

If you have e.g. a vector of integers:

```
std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

and want to print print them, then you could do:

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int val) { std::cout << val; });
```

The above call to `std::for_each` is equivalent to:

```
for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << *i;
}
```

---

Now if we go the usage of the [`std::istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) in the question, it is wrapping the input operator `>>` using iterators.

Rewriting the `std::for_each` call using standard C++ lambdas, it would look like this:

```
std::for_each(in(std::cin), in(), [](int value) { std::cout << (value * 3) << " " ); });
```

If we translate it to the "normal" `for` iterator loop then it becomes:

```
for (auto i = in(std::cin); i != in(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << (*i * 3) << " ";
}
```

What it does, is reading integer input (until end-of-file or an error) from `std::cin`, and then output the value multiplied by `3` and a space.

---

If you're wondering about `in(std::cin)` and `in()`, you have to remember that `in` is an alias for the type `std::istream_iterator<int>`.

That means `in(std::cin)` is the same as `std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin)`. I.e. it creates a `std::istream_iterator<int>` object, and passes `std::cin` to the constructor. And `in()` constructs an end-iterator object.

Making it even clearer, the code is equivalent to:

```
std::istream_iterator<int> the_beginning(std::cin);
std::istream_iterator<int> the_end;  // Default construct, becomes the "end" iterator

for (std::istream_iterator<int> i = the_beginning; i != the_end; ++i)
{
    int value = *i;  // Dereference iterator to get its value
                     // (effectively the same as std::cin >> value)

    std::cout << (value * 3) << " ";
}
```

Comment: thanks for the kind explanation! (but I knew the basic iterator usages, and you missed the explanation for the _1 so I chose the other answer.)

Comment: This answer is very useful. On the standard input `std::cin`, how does one enter / indicate that the stream is over thereby making `i == the_end` in the for loop?

Comment: @Tryer Most systems have a special key-combination that the terminal sends as `EOF`. On POSIX systems (like macOS or Linux) it's `Ctrl-D`, on Windows it's `Ctrl-Z` (on a new line).

Comment: I got piped data and `istream_iterator` doesn't work, it just skips doing nothing. executing `readsome` on `cin` does work though.